# Excel: Find minimal value in array from name

Tags: excel, indexing, min

I have a large csv file with temperature samples with 5 minutes interval. I have 30 sensors named S001 ~ S030.

```
date(A) time(B) network ID(C)   device type(D)  device ID(E)    sensor  data(F) channel(G)  data flags(H)   data sequence number(I) value(J)

    11-3-2019   00:01:28    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29560   3,9

    11-3-2019   00:03:27    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29561   3,9

    11-3-2019   00:05:25    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29562   3,9

    11-3-2019   00:07:22    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29563   3,9

    11-3-2019   00:09:20    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29564   4

    11-3-2019   00:11:18    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29565   4,1

    11-3-2019   00:13:16    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29566   4,2

    11-3-2019   00:15:14    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29567   4,2

    11-3-2019   00:17:12    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29568   4,2

    11-3-2019   00:19:10    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29569   4,2

    11-3-2019   00:21:08    6   1   1   S001 Buiten Temperature 128 29570   4,2
```

Somewhere around line 4500 starts S002.

Now I want to make a resume in another tab sheet with the minimal values from all sensors. So S0001 would need a search in array of column F2-F4500 where the name is and finding the minimal value from that array in column J2-J4500.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MINIFS() is available in Office 365 Excel or later.  Otherwise you will need to use an array formula `MIN(IF(condition,value))`

Comment: Thanks, =MIN.ALS.VOORWAARDEN(Export!$J2:$J100000;Export!$F2:$F100000;$D4) did the trick. Also =MAX.ALS.VOORWAARDEN(Export!$J2:$J100000;Export!$F2:$F100000;$D4) works for maximum values. Now I would need the same for the average value. Any ideas? {note: MIN.ALS.VOORWAARDEN = MINIFS in dutch}

Comment: Sure AVERAGEIFS()